# ANTLR4 grun rig doesn't appear to report tokens properly... do I understand this?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am testing some grammar with grun and I'm not seeing my tokens recognized as tokens. I initially thought perhaps I had created "implicit" tokens based on this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723840/antlr4-implicit-or-explicit-token-definition).

Also, in reviewing the output of grun -tokens, I found these links:
1) Recent [Change](http:////https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/e65154c1616f78b06fb81cb252b8a92508bf00e6) to -tokens output.
2) Possibly Outdated [testrig.md](https://github.com/mobileink/lab.clj.antlr/blob/master/doc/testrig.md) I've forked this and am digging into it.

Here is my simple HelloTC.g4 where I explore this:

```
grammar HelloTC;
r  : HELLO id; 
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
CMD: '%';
DIR: '%%';
A:   'A'; 
AA:  'AA';
HELLO:'hello';
ID : [a-z]+ ;
id :  DIR | CMD | A | AA;
```

I test this with:

```
grun HelloTC r -tokens
hello %%
hello %
hello A
hello AA
^Z

[@0,0:4='hello',<'hello'>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='%%',<'%%'>,1:6]
[@2,10:14='hello',<'hello'>,2:0]
[@3,16:16='%',<'%'>,2:6]
[@4,19:23='hello',<'hello'>,3:0]
[@5,25:25='A',<'A'>,3:6]
[@6,28:32='hello',<'hello'>,4:0]
[@7,34:35='AA',<'AA'>,4:6]
[@8,38:37='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
```

None of my tokens are recognized as tokens.
I was expecting:

```
[@0,0:4='hello',<HELLO>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='%%',<DIR>,1:6]
[@2,10:14='hello',<HELLO>,2:0]
[@3,16:16='%',<CMD>,2:6]
[@4,19:23='hello',<HELLO>,3:0]
[@5,25:25='A',<A>,3:6]
[@6,28:32='hello',<HELLO>,4:0]
[@7,34:35='AA',<AA>,4:6]
[@8,38:37='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
```

In my expected results I replaced 'chars' with TOKEN NAME.

I ran antlr4 with -Xlog and my tokens are declared (second to last line), so now I'm wondering if I just mis-understand what the grun log reports.  I expected the data in <> to be the TOKEN name passed by the lexer.  Do I have that incorrectly?

What can I do to my grammar to get the tokens to be recognized as tokens?
OR... how does one debug a grammer to ensure the lexer is identifying tokens correctly?

Here is my -Xlog file:

```
2017-01-20 06:57:29:640 grammar LogManager.java:25 before: (COMBINED_GRAMMAR HelloTC (RULES (RULE r (BLOCK (ALT HELLO id))) (RULE WS (BLOCK (LEXER_ALT_ACTION (ALT (+ (BLOCK (ALT [ \r\t\n])))) skip))) (RULE CMD (BLOCK (ALT '%cat'))) (RULE DIR (BLOCK (ALT '%%'))) (RULE A (BLOCK (ALT 'A'))) (RULE AA (BLOCK (ALT 'AA'))) (RULE HELLO (BLOCK (ALT 'hello'))) (RULE id (BLOCK (ALT DIR) (ALT CMD) (ALT A) (ALT AA)))))
2017-01-20 06:57:29:661 grammar LogManager.java:25 after: (COMBINED_GRAMMAR HelloTC (RULES (RULE r (BLOCK (ALT HELLO id))) (RULE WS (BLOCK (LEXER_ALT_ACTION (ALT (+ (BLOCK (ALT [ \r\t\n])))) skip))) (RULE CMD (BLOCK (ALT '%cat'))) (RULE DIR (BLOCK (ALT '%%'))) (RULE A (BLOCK (ALT 'A'))) (RULE AA (BLOCK (ALT 'AA'))) (RULE HELLO (BLOCK (ALT 'hello'))) (RULE id (BLOCK (ALT (SET DIR CMD A AA))))))
2017-01-20 06:57:29:694 grammar LogManager.java:25 after extract implicit lexer =(COMBINED_GRAMMAR HelloTC (RULES (RULE r (BLOCK (ALT HELLO id))) (RULE id (BLOCK (ALT (SET DIR CMD A AA))))))
2017-01-20 06:57:29:694 grammar LogManager.java:25 lexer =(LEXER_GRAMMAR HelloTCLexer (RULES (RULE WS (BLOCK (LEXER_ALT_ACTION (ALT (+ (BLOCK (ALT [ \r\t\n])))) skip))) (RULE CMD (BLOCK (ALT '%cat'))) (RULE DIR (BLOCK (ALT '%%'))) (RULE A (BLOCK (ALT 'A'))) (RULE AA (BLOCK (ALT 'AA'))) (RULE HELLO (BLOCK (ALT 'hello')))))
2017-01-20 06:57:30:040 semantics LogManager.java:25 tokens={EOF=-1, WS=1, CMD=2, DIR=3, A=4, AA=5, HELLO=6}
2017-01-20 06:57:30:040 semantics LogManager.java:25 strings={'%cat'=2, '%%'=3, 'A'=4, 'AA'=5, 'hello'=6}
```

An example of the type of syntax I'm trying to create a grammar for is below.

```
//COMMENTS
;comments
%%DIRECTIVEA
%%DIRECTIVEB
RESERVED_TOKEN(ARGS,ARGS)
%commandA
 commandB
 commandD
 commandE
 ...
 CommandH  (only A-H allowed)
// comments
%commandB
%%DIRECTIVEB
%commandD
 commandE
%commandA
 done
```

I'm still digging and running experiments.  Hopefully this question, and any answers will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised too. In previous releases, the name of tokens was not even translated :

```
[@0,0:4='hello',<6>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='%%',<3>,1:6]
[@2,9:13='hello',<6>,2:0]
[@3,15:15='%',<2>,2:6]
[@4,17:21='hello',<6>,3:0]
[@5,23:23='A',<4>,3:6]
[@6,25:29='hello',<6>,4:0]
[@7,31:32='AA',<5>,4:6]
[@8,34:33='<EOF>',<-1>,5:0]
```

Years ago I had written a Ruby script to translate `<n>` into its name by fetching the `<grammar>.tokens` file. It's now done in 4.6.

If you define HELLO and ID this way and in this sequence :

```
HELLO
    : [a-z]+ {getText().equals("hello")}? ;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
```

with this input

```
    hello %%
...
    hello xyz
```

you have this result :

```
    [@0,0:4='hello',<HELLO>,1:0]
    [@1,6:7='%%',<'%%'>,1:6]
...
    [@8,34:38='hello',<HELLO>,5:0]
    [@9,40:42='xyz',<ID>,5:6]
```

The input `hello` is ambiguous, it can be matched by two rules. The syntactic predicate in the lexer rule allows the lexer to choose `HELLO` when the input is `hello`.

We can conclude that constants are represented by themselves, and other input by the token name. Despite of this curiosity, your tokens are correctly recognized. If it weren't the case, the parser would complain :
input `hello %% 123` gives :

```
$ grun Question r -tokens data.txt 
line 1:9 token recognition error at: '1'
line 1:10 token recognition error at: '2'
line 1:11 token recognition error at: '3'
[@0,0:4='hello',<HELLO>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='%%',<'%%'>,1:6]
```

If you add an INT rule in the grammar

```
INT : [0-9]+ ;
```

then the new token is recognized :

```
[@0,0:4='hello',<HELLO>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='%%',<'%%'>,1:6]
[@2,9:11='123',<INT>,1:9]
```

Comment: After additional testing, I was able to convince myself that the grammar/lexer I had defined was working.  I did notice that the testrig annotation of TOKEN_NAME was a newer feature in ANTLR after digging.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect. grun output still doesn't output my tokens..but I can continue learning targeting Java by inserting System.out.printlin() actions. 
The downside is that after I'm done, I have to pull these debug clauses out.
Ultimately my target parser will be python based. But I'm still on the learning curve in Java.

This [link](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md) shows how to use actions for debugging.

With that, I modifed my HelloTC.gr to:

```
grammar HelloTC;
r  : HELLO id+ {System.out.println("r rule encountered");};
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
CMD: '%' {System.out.println("Lexer found a CMD");};
DIR: '%%'{System.out.println("Lexer found a DIR");};
A:   'A';
AA:  'AA';
HELLO:'hello'{System.out.println("Lexer found a HELLO");};
ID : [a-z]+ ;
id :  DIR | CMD | A | AA { System.out.println("Parser found rule match "+$text);};
```

And debugging it with grun yields:

```
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig HelloTC r -tokens
hello%%
hello %%
^Z
Lexer found a HELLO
Lexer found a DIR
Lexer found a HELLO
Lexer found a DIR
[@0,0:4='hello',<'hello'>,1:0]
[@1,5:6='%%',<'%%'>,1:5]
[@2,9:13='hello',<'hello'>,2:0]
[@3,15:16='%%',<'%%'>,2:6]
[@4,19:18='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
line 2:0 extraneous input 'hello' expecting {<EOF>, '%', '%%', 'A', 'AA'}
r rule encountered
```

So the good news is that the Lexer rules are being seen, and I have a technique for analysis/debug.  I think to understand/decipher grun more I will have to look into the sources more...thatleads to wanting to "build/test" modifications to antlr which is a slippery slope. I'm trying to focus on my original task...
which is developing a parser.